# Compiling with "latex" instead of "pdflatex" command leads to upward movement of text body

Tags: margins, geometry

I am writing a thesis with specific margin requirements.  I am using a template recently created (read: untested?) by someone else.  The problem is that when I use my computer's `latex` command the text is offset vertically by about an inch for every page in the document; however, `pdflatex` creates a document with the proper margins and the text body not being offset vertically.  My .log file says that the version of `latex`/`pdflatex` I am using is: Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6) (format=pdflatex 2013.5.21).  Why does `pdflatex` compile with the correct margins while `latex` doesn't?

I am using the Redhat 6 distribution of Linux.

This is enough for me to reproduce the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}   
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that `geometry` does not work well with `latex` and `dvi`.

Comment: What type of paper are you using? If it's US Letter, pass the `letterpaper` option to `geometry`.

Comment: It is US Letter.  I just tried the `letterpaper` option and it did not work.

Comment: @sigur `geometry` works fine with `latex+dvips`. This is more likely a configuration problem.

Comment: @Joshua From the command line (you don't say what OS you are using) what does `tlmgr paper` return? What is your TeX distribution and OS?

Comment: How are you viewing the output of latex?

Comment: @AlanMunn, yes, you are right. It is necessary to pass to `ps`.

Comment: @AlanMunn I am using Redhat 6 Lilnux.  `tlmgr paper` returns `tlmgr: Command not found`.  I am unsure how to find my TeX distribution.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am viewing the pdf using Okular.  I also tried emailing the PDF to myself and viewing it with gmail.

Comment: Well latex creates a dvi. So how are you generating the pdf from the dvi?

Comment: To sort out what your defaults are, try `latex testpage.tex` and follow the prompts.  It will output a `.dvi` that shows how things are being aligned on the LaTeX side of things.  Mine ends up being off if I select `a4paper` instead of `letterpaper`.  You can also use `pdflatex testpage.tex`, but if you are going DVI --> PDF, that is probably less helpful....

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use the `dvipdf` command to convert the `.dvi` to `.pdf`.

Comment: @joshua Try doing the following: `sudo texconfig-sys paper letter` and see if that changes things.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use the `dvipdf` command to convert the `.dvi` to `.pdf`. However, when I use Okular to view the `.pdf` the file name shown on the top of the Okular window shows `.dvi` even though I specifically open a `.pdf`.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I can't run `sudo texconfig-sys paper letter` because I am not a System Administrator.  I tried.

Comment: @Joshua There's a non-system version you can try: `texconfig paper letter` will create a local version of the config file with `letter` size paper.

Comment: @AlanMunn for future reference how would I undo the `texconfig paper letter` command?  That command did the trick by the way.  I guess a better question would be, what was `paper` set to before?  I don't know if that's a question you can answer without looking at my machine.

Comment: Joshua -- The options are `letterpaper` and `a4paper`; I told you a very simple way to test: run the command from a terminal: `latex testpage.tex` and follow the prompts and see if the resulting `.dvi` is correctly aligned or not (when you look at the `.dvi` it will be obvious).

Comment: @Joshua The paper was most likely set to A4.  In TeXLive 2010 there was a bug in which the paper size for `dvips` was set to `a4` even when the other programs' paper size was set to `letter`. I suspect this was the source of the problem, although I can't tell for sure. The local configuration file is called `config.ps` and is located in the local `TEXMFCONFIG/dvips/config`. This file can be deleted (it's in your home folder).  Of course this will cause the system version (which is incorrect) to be used.  Ideally you should get an admin to run the admin version of the command for you.

Comment: When you are using dvipdf to convert the dvi you perhaps need a different driver for geometry depending on what dvipdf is actually doing. Check the documentation for the option names and try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symptoms you are describing are usually indicative of a misconfigured distribution. Although to the end user the paper size seems just to work, it is in fact configurable for various different binaries used by the system, specifically the programs `dvips`, `dvipdfm`, `pdftex` and `xdvi`.  In particular, the symptoms are emblematic of the paper size for the `dvips` program incorrectly set to `a4`, while the `pdftex` setting is correctly set to `letter`.

On a standard TeX Live system, (i.e. one installed directly from the TeX Live web page (Windows or Linux) or the MacTeX distribution) these settings are set once at installation time, but can be changed using the `tlmgr` program.  If using `tlmgr` the paper size for all programs can be set to `letter` by using the following command:

```
tlmgr paper letter
```

However, in Linux packaged systems, `tlmgr` is *not* installed, and the configuration must be done differently.

If not using `tlmgr`, there are two commands to set various configuration settings: `texconfig-sys` and `texconfig`. The former command sets the global configuration, and must be run with `sudo` (requires admin access).  The other version of the command creates a local configuration, which is stored in the `TEXMFCONFIG` folder in the user's home directory.

So to change the paper size setting for the `dvips` program to `letter` (the correct setting for your system) you need to use one of the following commands, depending on whether you have admin access or not:

```
texconfig-sys dvips paper letter

texconfig dvips paper letter
```

How did this misconfiguration arise?  I can't say for sure, but in the 2010 TeX Live there was a bug which resulted in exactly this situation: `dvips` paper size was set to `a4` when other programs were set to `letter`.  It's possible that the RedHat Linux package has perpetuated this bug, or simply that the system was misconfigured in some other way.